# ActivityManager: Start Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME]}

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a app on my android device that runs as a `system_process`.

It's doing `USB` communication in `JNI layer`, with a full screen `UI` to show images.

The problem is, the activity becomes invisible not long after start up. I can see from `logcat` that the `onStop()` was called.

And when I click the app icon the make it foreground, it would disappear again later.

I looked into the `logcat` to find that when this happens, there is a message like:

```
ActivityManager: Start Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME]}
```

I don't know whether this means the home key is pressed.

Actually I was not pressing that. But this indeed makes my app goes background and the home page was showed.

I try to add `"android.intent.category.HOME"` in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. It does not work.

My question is, what triggers `ActivityManager` to `"Start Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME]}"` ?

It seems the event is raise at random time.

Can I capture & ignore this event to prevent my app from becoming invisible ?

By the way, my device has `android 4.1.2` version.

Answer (score 1):

All right. Seems there is something wrong with my device. When I run the app on other device, I did not encounter this problem.